# Extreme problems - something is eating up all disk space constantly

Tags: disk-usage, teamviewer

I have so much trouble with disk space, it's crazy. My HDD constantly gets full even though I have 2 TB. I figured out fairly quickly that the file .xsession-errors was huge and eating up a big part of the disk space (several hundred GB). I think this is caused thanks to the program Teamviewer, it says something about vino-server and when Teamviewer is running it always ends up under the vino-symbol (the glass). The file always  explodes in size when Teamviewer is running. I've removed .xsession-errors and restarted the computer countless times. But I really need to run Teamviewer as I use it every day.

Naturally I've spent a lot of time Googling on how to deal with the .xsession-errors file. I tried a couple of things that didn't work. The one that did seem to work, because .xsession-errors was at 0 kB constantly, was the `chattr -i` command that keeps the file open and don't let anything write to it. Problem solved.. or so I thought.

Something is -still- eating up all the disk space, but this time I can't find the problem! I can't find any file that is taking up all the space. Now I'm getting so many problems I can't even restart the computer because there is no disk space available.

I enter my user with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>, and I have to delete huge folders (>20GB) I don't really want to delete, but I have to in order to be able to start the computer properly.

Please help?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 64 bit. Teamviewer is the latest version available on their website, v8.0.17147.

Comment: I usually use `du` to find offending folders - I find it easiest to use `du -d 1 | sort -h` to only top level folders sorted by size, move into the abnormally large folder, then use `ls -l | sort -k5 -h` to find the largest files. Rinse and repeat as necessary through the tree of folders to find the problem.

Comment: Thank you Drake. I've already done that! I've started from / and looked through everything. My home directory is 1.1 TB and that is how big it should be, but my HDD is supposed to be ~2TB and it is full already! Is there any other way??

Comment: what are your results of `df -h`? of `du -d1 / | sort -h`?

Comment: That shows you with 111 gigs free... although if you have 1.1 TB in /home, I don't know here the other 400 or so gigs are at. At most 20 of it would be for the system.

Comment: Sorry I tried to format the comment to make it readable but don't know how. So I deleted it. Let me write it instead. It says 1.7 TB but df without -h gives closer to 1.8 TB, same with Avail, more closer to 1.6 TB. That is actually another question of mine, why different disk space programs gives completely different output how much disk space you have, some say 1.9, some 2 TB, but df says almost 1.8, but I thought I save that question for another time.

Comment: The only reason it says 111G available is because I deleted 3 folders with > 100GB on it (which I didn't want to delete), otherwise I was unable to start Ubuntu at all. Before that it said 0 available.

Comment: and 'du -c' in home gives only a total of 1.1 TB. Where is the rest taking up space??

Comment: du -d1 / | sort -h   gives 1.1 TB in home and 1.7 TB in / !

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the full results of the `du -d1 / | sort -h` command above? And the 1.1TB in home is normal you said? What do you have in there?

Comment: I found the problem, the file that was eating up all disk space! It was in /var/log/. It was called lightdm.log and it was 450 GB. I removed that one together with lightdm.log.*.gz files, and they totaled of around 500 GB. Don't worry about home being big, it's my work computer and I'm analyzing very big files. However, the problem is not solved yet. But I tried a new method, I'm hoping it will work this time and stop it from eating up all disk space! I linked the .xsession-errors file to /dev/null/. Thank you so much Drake Clarris for your help, do you have any other suggestion for me?

Comment: I one time had X session logs growing enormously like that, but it was on cygwin. And update fixed it for me. Not sure what you can do - Make sure lightdm and whatever desktop you use is up to date. Maybe try another desktop to use with teamviewer if it persists to see if one doesn't grow the logs like that.